# New Line in textarea problem

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Hello all I created a textarea and I can "enter" a new line in it all day but when I submit the box.  Its all one continuous sentence.  Any thoughts??

```
<tr id="commentRow">              
         <td>
         You have <strong><span id="commentsCounter">${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH'] - fn:length(commentForm.comment)}</span></strong> characters left.<br/>
            <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="2" cols="125" style="width:360px;"
                 onkeypress="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeydown="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"
                 onkeyup="characterCounter('commentsCounter',${const['COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH']}, this)"></textarea>

                    <a href="javascript:addComment();"><img src="../images/icon_add.gif" border="0" alt="Add"/></a>
        </td>
        <td class="shaded" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

is there something I need to add to the jsp??

Hey buddy below this is prior to adding the

```
<form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" action="" method="post">
<ctl:vertScroll height="300" headerStyleClass="data_table_scroll"      bodyStyleClass="data_table_scroll" enabled="${user.scrollTables}">
<ctl:sortableTblHdrSetup topTotal="false" href="show.whatif_edit_entry?entryId=${entry.entryId}"/>
<table class="data_table vert_scroll_table" style="width:360px;">
    <tr>
    <ctl:sortableTblHdr styleClass="center"  title="Comments" property="comment" type="top">Comments</ctl:sortableTblHdr>    
    <ctl:sortableTblHdr styleClass="center"  title="Created By" property="auditable.createdBy.lastName" type="top">Entered By</ctl:sortableTblHdr>

    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="comments" items="${entry.comments}">


        <tr id="id${comments.id}">
        <td id="comments-${comments.id}" class="wrappable" style="width:360px;" >${comments.comment}</td>
```

[image]

Then I added the

`<tr id="id${comments.id}">
        <td id="comments-${comments.id}" class="wrappable" style="width:360px;" ><pre>${comments.comment}</pre></td>`

The table then expanded HUGE!!!!!

[image]

any thoughts???

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this more of a JavaScript problem than a Java problem? Should your "java" tag be changed?

Comment: I have no idea if its a javascript issue..but thanx!

Comment: You do know the difference between Java and JavaScript, right?

Comment: yeah...one has the word script after it....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display data from a textarea as html you will need to convert any `\n` characters into `<br>` (or `<br />` for XHTML) tags, otherwise they'll show up in your source but not on your page.

Alternatively wrapping the whole thing in `<pre></pre>` tags will also work as this will treat the text as pre-formatted and display it like a text editor (saving tabs and whitespace).

If you were to output whatever is entered in the textarea into the `<td class="shaded">` you'd change that to `<td class="shaded" colspan="1"><pre>`*textarea input displayed here*`</pre></td>`

Comment: You mean wrap the textare box in <pre></pre>??

Comment: No, take the input of the textarea, go to where you want to display it, wrap it in `<pre>` tags there.

Comment: ok..that seemed to work...it had some unexpected results in the box....but thanx...I might submit another question tommorrow to show you how it looks after rendering

Comment: Hey Alexander I edited the question after inserting the <pre>'s...take a look

Comment: Try adding the width to the pre tags too, it seems to have some side effects on the behaviour of tablecells.

Comment: Thanks....our dev database is down, so i cant do any work...I will let you know how it goes

Comment: Hey...the width attribute didnt work....should I format it a certan way???....this is baffling

Comment: Google tells me there's some weird behavioru with <pre> in table cells. Not sure why or what the fix is : (

Answer (score 1):

However you are displaying the submitted data probably isn't taking into account the newline characters that you are submitting.  I would see if there are any \r or \n characters to change to new lines "`<br />`" in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use this in textarea value to break line to new

```
\n\n
```

tested as required